# Can't activate Server Publishing

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, master-page

I'm trying to activate the SharePoint 2010 Server Publishing on a site and it gives the following message:

`Site`

`The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa`

`Web`

`The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden Site scoped feature 'FeatureDefinition/22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416' (ID: '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416'). Hidden features cannot be auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden feature.`

The SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is already Active on the site collection. I'm using the v4.master. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try de-activating and re-activating the Publishing Infrastructure feature for the site collection (assuming you don't have other publishing sites). You may get another error message which you can follow to find what is missing.

Make sure you are activating the Publishing Infrastructure feature for the correct site collection. Go to your site's Site Actions->Site Settings. If the site is not the top-level site of the site collection, follow the link to Go to top-level site settings (note that you need to be a site collection administrator). Then go to Site Collection Features in order to activate the Publishing Infrastructure feature.

Comment: Thanks, SPDoctor. I did just as you indicated. Then I also noticed that the Site Collection Feature available from the site itself had the Publishing Infrastructure deactivated; not sure how it could be active at the root but not at this level. Once I activated at this level, then Server Publishing could be activated. Strange.

Comment: It sounds as though there are two Site Collections involved here. Did you activate the Publishing Infrastructure site collection on the Central Administration site by mistake (I know quite a few people have done this)?

Comment: I've been looking at the Central Admin. and can't figure out where to check for the site collection features.

Comment: The site collection features are with the site collection and not central admin.  Go to your root site for the collection.  In the Site Settings page, there is a section for Site collection administration.  There is a link for site collection features in this section.

Comment: Okay, I think you may have been activating the Publishing Infrastructure feature on your Central Administration site collection. I'll update my answer as this can catch people out.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. So, to clarify, I need to activate the feature on the site collection of the sub-site, not the root? For example, if my main root is `http://vmdev139/` and the sub-site is `http://vmdev139/helpdesk/`, I'd activate it on the helpdesk site collection by going to the root of that site.

Comment: You need to activate the Publishing Infrastructure feature on the site collection to which the site belongs. You may have many site collections in your web application with different paths - which one is at the root URL is not relevant. Go to the subsite and use Site Settings to take you to the settings for the top-level site.

Answer (score 1):

If this does not work via the UI, you can try the same thing (de-activate - activate) through the command line on the server with the STSADM tool.  The command would be:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa -url "http://*url of site collection*" -force

stsadm -o activatefeature -id f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa -url "http://*url of site collection*" -force
```

If you want to do this in PowerShell, run these commands in the SharePoint PowerShell window.

```
Disable-SPFeature FeatureFolderName -Url "http://*url of site collection*"
Enable-SPFeature FeatureFolderName -Url "http://*url of site collection*"
```